# How to classList.add() in react for material makeStyles css?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, material-ui

here is my styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
   button1: {
    border: 0,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: ' hidden',
    color: '#FFF',
    backgroundColor: '#7768F2',
     '&circle': {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: '#dd8164',
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
      borderRadius: '48px',
      transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)',
      animation: 'scale 0.5s ease-out',
     },
  },
  
  '@keyframes scale': {
    to: {
      transform: 'tranlate(-50%,-50%) scale (3)',
      opacity: '0.5',
    },
  },

});


export default useStyles;
```

and here is where I wanna use it

```
import useStyles from './styles';
import React from 'react';
function Landing() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function onRippleStart(e) {
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    const buttonTop = e.target.offsetTop;
    const buttonLeft = e.target.offsetLeft;
    const xInside = x - buttonLeft;
    const yInside = y - buttonTop;
    const circle = document.createElement('span');
    circle.classList.add(classes.circle);
```

here I want to select the circle inside the button1 but the created span keeps having a class of undefined. It doesn't work either when I use  `classList.add('circle');` which creates a class circle without using the one I defined in my styles.

what would be the correct syntax for using adding the circle? something like`classList.add(classes.button1.circle);`

Answer (score -2):

### Make sure you Pull the answer if it helps you.

You can use state and dynamically  add and remove the class using react.
Initially, set state to the false i.e :-

```
const [state,setState]= useState(false);
```

Then, when you click the button change the state to the true :

```
const changeStyle =()=>{
setState(true)
}
```

Then, finally check the condition to add and remove the class to your div or whatever.

```
<div className={"oldClass" state === true ? "newClass" : "" }> Hi coders</div>
<button onClick={changeStyle}>Change CSS</button>
```

Make sure you previously give styling to the newClass in CSS.